# Android Studio position the standard checkbox background to the left border in the checkbox?

Tags: android

I am trying to **line up my views**, but since the `CheckBox` view area is bigger than the actual background, it appears to be **out of proportion**.

The image below demonstrates my problem

[image]

As you can see it is not lined up with the input fields below.
Is there any way to **push the background to the left border?**

The `xml` for the `layout` is below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="@drawable/list_item_palegrey_border_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/topSpace"/>

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/milageHeader"
    android:layout_below="@id/topSpace"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/milageLabel"
            android:text="Milersättning:"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/milageCheckBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="40%"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>


<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/milageContent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@id/milageHeader">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/kilometersContainer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/kilometersLabel"
            android:text="Antal körda km:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <EditText
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border_square"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:id="@+id/kilometersEditText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kilometersLabel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/kilometersLabel"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fromCityPlaceContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kilometersContainer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/fromCityPlaceLabel"
            android:text="Från ort/plats:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <EditText
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:background="@drawable/border_square"
            android:id="@+id/fromCityPlaceEditText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fromCityPlaceLabel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/fromCityPlaceLabel"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toCityPlaceContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fromCityPlaceContainer">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/toCityPlaceLabel"
            android:text="Till ort/plats:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <EditText
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/toCityPlaceEditText"
            android:background="@drawable/border_square"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toCityPlaceLabel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toCityPlaceLabel"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/returnContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toCityPlaceContainer">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/returnLabel"
            android:text="Tur och retur:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/returnCheckBix"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/returnLabel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/returnLabel"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/purposeContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/returnContainer">

        <TextView
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/purposeLabel"
            android:text="Syfte:"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:id="@+id/purposeEditText"
            android:background="@drawable/border_square"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/purposeLabel"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/purposeLabel"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/milageContent"/>
```

Comment: can you post your layout file

Comment: @AdityaDesai I updated the post, have a look

Comment: try setting padding 0 on the checkbox

Comment: @TimCastelijns tried it, no further success

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `android:translationX="-7dp"` to the `CheckBox` which moved the background to the left border.

[image]